# Calling public class method within string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to insert a public class method within the payload of a POST call. The code I've written:

```
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post,
                          url: $url,
                          payload: '{"event" : "start_skill",
                                    "uuid" : "RandomSecure.uuid"}',
                          headers: {"Content-Type" => "application/json"})
```

So what I am trying to do is for this call to generate a new UUID each time the call is made. The problem, obviously, is the fact that the entire payload is in single quotation marks (e.g. ' ). I've tried wrapping the UUID in single quotation marks, but that does not generate the same output. I've also tried #{, but that does not work either.

What else could I try for the UUID method to be called upon without changing the message?

Comment: First, why IS your entire payload quoted (a string)? Second, why is your uuid expression a string, `"RandomSecure.uuid"`? That's a literal string. Third, it's `SecureRandom`, not `RandomSecure`.

Comment: Honestly I am still a rookie at Ruby, and this is based off an example I found online. That is why I had the entire payload quoted. Obviously not the most ideal situation. And thank you for pointing that out, my fault, did not realize I had Random and Secury backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could go. You could use an interpolated string (string with double quotes `"like this"`, and indeed use `#{}` within this string. However, you would need to manually escape every single `"` in your string which can become hassle.

The other method would be to make a hash with your desired json data, and call `.to_json` on it.(note: you need to add `require 'json'`.

```
{ event: "start_skill", uuid: RandomSecure.uuid }.to_json
```

Which would result in:

```
"{\"event\":\"start_skill\", \"udid\": \"some random udid\"}"
```

So to wrap it up:

```
# somewhere at the top of your file
require 'json'

payload = { event: "start_skill", uuid: RandomSecure.uuid }.to_json
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post,
                            url: $url,
                            payload: payload,
                            headers: { "Content-Type" => "application/json" })
```